# It takes half a second to persist an entity (JPA/Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm not very experienced with hibernate, but this seems way too much.

When I'm trying to persist a very simple entity, such as this:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    String somePropery;

    public String getSomePropery() {
        return somePropery;
    }

    public void setSomePropery(String somePropery) {
        this.somePropery = somePropery;
    }

}
```

It takes 0.7 seconds.
Am I right that it should be way less? If so, what is the reason?

This is my configuration:

```
spring.dataSource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.dataSource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.max-active=5

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true

spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Update:

I use spring data JPA, and this is the test that runs:

```
@Test
public void test(){
    SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity();
    someEntityRepository.save(entity);
}
```

someEntityRepository is a JpaRepository.

Comment: What do you measure exactly? Where is the code for your benchmark?

Comment: `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` isn't doing you any favours; what's the rest of the logging turned to?

Comment: have you verified that the connection pool is actually allocating the proper number of connections on boot at not at initial use?  I could see interaction time with the datasource being longer if it has to negotiate a connection each time.